# Range loop where value of a cell is blank

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, foreach, vba

I have set a range. A few cells in that range have values and lot of cells do not have values, they are blank. I have a range loop that is taking time because it processes every cell:

```
For Each cel1 In rngsh1
```

The above processes all cells in the range.

What is the exact syntax where the range loop processes only non-blank cells?

Something like `For Each cel11 in rngsh1 and not nothing` I know this syntax is wrong but I am looking for a correct one.

Comment: `For Each cel11 in rngsh1` and then `If Len(Cel1.Value) > 0 Then`

Comment: Thanks... let me try this

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(cel1.Value) Then` :P

Comment: both works like charm. This will check only non-blank cells. If I need to check for cells only with specific string then? do I need to start a new question for this? my strings are "center1" "center5" "center8" "center9". I have 54 such centers. If the range loop finds any of these centers in a non-bank cell then only i need to processes some information.

Comment: For instance I have all my strings "center1" "center5" "center8" and so on... in a particular range `I1:BJ1` if cel1 value is one among these 54 values only then go ahead. how to write syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
Dim cel11 As Range
Dim rngsh1 As Range

'Function MultiOr(str As String, ParamArray arr() As Variant) As Boolean
'  Dim holder, runner
'  MultiOr = True
'  For Each holder In arr 'look for everything in arr
'    If IsArray(holder) Then 'if what you found is an array
'      For Each runner In holder 'for everything in that array
'        If MultiOr(str, runner) Then Exit Function 
'      Next
'    Else 'if its no array
'      If Not IsMissing(holder) Then If holder = str Then Exit Function
'    End If
'  Next
'  MultiOr = False
'End Function

Sub MySub()
  For Each cel1 In Range
'   If Not IsEmpty(cel1.Value) Then 'see EEM's answer
    If Len(cel1.Value) > 0 Then 
'     If MultiOr(cel1.Value, condi) Then 'no need for this function 
      If Not IsError(Application.Match(cel1.Value, Range("I1:BJ1"), 0)) Then
        'your code here
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub

'`condi` can be a range with all the conditions or an array or simply a value...
```

Comment: Oops! this is too tough for me to understand. If I have my strings in `I1:BJ1` then will the line be `If MultiOr(cel1.Value, I1:BJ1) Then`

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, For instance I have all my strings "center1" "center5" "center8" and so on... in a particular range I1:BJ1 if cel1 value is one among these 54 values only then go ahead. how to write syntax for this? Will this function help me?

Comment: `MultoOr(value, array)` just checks if anything in `array` equals `value`... so just change `If MultiOr(cel1.Value, condi) Then` to `If MultiOr(cel1.Value, Range("I1:BJ1")) Then`
...it will check everything in I1:BJ1 = cel1.Value

Comment: Got it.. thank you very much. One question out of curiosity, Is it really required to write a function to achieve what I am looking for? I just want to check the `cel1` value if it is present in my range `I1:BJ1`. Is there not any shorter line to convert a long line like `if cel1.value=[i1].value or cel1.value=[j1].value or cel1.value=[k1].value or ...... Then`

Comment: You could use `If Not IsError (Application.Match(cel1.Value, Range("I1:BJ1"), 0)) Then`...
I like my `MultiOr` cus its able to work with arrays containing arrays... However `Match` will also do it in this case...
Also edited the answer and remembered the reason for always using `Len(...) > 0`... Thanks to EEM :)
you can also put the `Len` and `Match` in one line like: `If Len(cel1.Value) > 0 And Not IsError(Application.Match(cel1.Value, Range("I1:BJ1"), 0)) Then`

Comment: in the first place, my answer still shows what it was b4. i just changed 2 little functions. while `Match` is not as "powerfull" as my own function, the requester asked for it (indirectly) -> no need to write `MultiOr` -> the real function remains (`MySub`). also as written in the first comment i'd prefer `Len` > someone mentioned the `IsEmpty` (but deleted his comment after i mentioned the missing `not`). however: never ask for an answer-upvote!
2 hints: see my first comment at your answer and `Rng.Value = Rng.Value2` will replace all formulas in range with their values

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. Efficiency in various methods would help only if the data is huge and time is the constraint otherwise all methods would give you what you are trying to achieve. Thanks you guys for the comments. Really appreciate. God bless!

Answer (score 1):

To really search through non-blank cells need to use the SpecialCells Range Method (see [Range.SpecialCells Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx)

This procedure process only non-blank cells

As some of the resources used in the procedure might be new to the user therefore I suggest to visit [Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx), nevertheless let me know of any question you might have about the code.

```
Sub Search_NonBlank_Cells()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim rCll As Range

    Rem Set Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(kRng)

    Rem Ensure blank intended cells are actually blank
    Rng.Value = Rng.Value2

    Rem Loop Through Non-Blank Cells Only
    For Each rCll In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, _
        xlErrors + xlLogical + xlNumbers + xlTextValues)

        Rem Validate if cell value starts with "center"
        If Left(rCll.Value2, 6) = "center" Then
            Rem Validate if remaining cell value is between 1 to 54
            Select Case Application.Substitute(rCll.Value2, "center", "")
            Case 1 To 54
                Rem Process Cell Found
                rCll.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    End Select: End If: Next

End Sub
```

This is the same procedure including some lines that will help you to debug and understand the process, also generates a log in the immediate window.

```
Sub Search_NonBlank_Cells_Debug()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim rCll As Range

: SendKeys "^g^a{DEL}": Stop
: Debug.Print vbLf; Now
: Debug.Print "Address"; Tab(11); "Cll.Value"; Tab(31); "Status"

    Rem Set Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(kRng)

    Rem Ensure blank intended cells are actually blank
    'i.e. Cells with formulas results as "" are not blank cell this makes then blank cells
    Rng.Value = Rng.Value2

    Rem Loop Through Non-Blank Cells Only
    For Each rCll In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, _
        xlErrors + xlLogical + xlNumbers + xlTextValues)

: Debug.Print rCll.Address; Tab(11); rCll.Value2;

        Rem Validate if cell value starts with "center"
        If Left(rCll.Value2, 6) = "center" Then
            Rem Validate if remaining cell value is between 1 to 54
            Select Case Application.Substitute(rCll.Value2, "center", "")

            Case 1 To 54
                Rem Process Cell Found
: Debug.Print Tab(31); "Processed"
                rCll.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

            Case Else
: Debug.Print Tab(31); "Skipped"

            End Select
        Else
: Debug.Print Tab(31); "Skipped"

    End If: Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @DirkReichel. I got that from OP's comments. If so then It will be more efficient to have the expected values listed in a worksheets and to compare against that range. It's also required to know if searching for whole or partial values within cells. Op's just let us know to adjust procedure.